# How can I make a user provide its own function in my library?

Tags: c, callback, avr, spi

I am writing a static library for an AVR MCU. I am using avr-gcc and AVR Libc. Some of the library functions use SPI to communicate with a device. However, SPI communication is not done the same way on all AVR MCUs (not all of them have the same registers concerned). It can even be done by big-banging. Thus, I want the user to provide its own SPI routine, for its specific application.

How can I do this? Should all the library functions take a callback function as an additional argument? Should I have a global variable within the library acting as an SPI handler? Should I make the function external (using `extern`)?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you need to choose at compile time (e.g. you can link in one particular SPI library), or at run time (e.g. you have to choose among a bunch of libraries linked in)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple and straightforward solution is to just declare an appropriately named extern function. This lets you compile your library without the extern function yet existing. But neither you or your users will be able to link a complete executable without providing an appropriate function.

I've used this approach myself and recommend it. It avoids unnecessary complications, uses nothing that isn't absolutely fundamental to all C programming environments, and importantly obvious errors will be flagged at build time not at run time (you won't get runtime crashes as undefined callback functions are called).

Comment: Just make sure the requirement to include your own SPI handler is clear in your documentation.

Comment: If it makes sense to provide a "default" implementation for such functions (i.e. an implementation which should be used in absence of user provided functions), you can do so with `avr-gcc` by providing a default implementation in your library but declaring its symbols with `__attribute__((weak))`. This will hide problems like the library user only implementing one required function but not another at compile and link time, though. This may not be useful to your specific SPI issue (*making* the user provide functions), but may be good for other things (*allowing* the user to provide functions).